# Suggestion regarding my proof regarding a closed set

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove the following theorem:

If $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $(x_{n})$ a convergent sequence in $A \subset M$, and its limit is in $A$, then $A$ is closed.

My proof: Let's assume $A$ is not closed, which means $A^{C}$ is not open.
Therefore $\exists x\in A^{C} \forall \epsilon>0:U_{\epsilon}(x) \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I suspect the statement was supposed to be "If for **any** sequence, {$a_n$} in A, the limit is in A then A is closed."

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is false: take $M = \mathbb R$ with its usual metric, $A = (0,1)$ and $x_n = \tfrac12$ for all $n$.

The correct statement should be the following:

> If $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $A$ a subset of $M$ with the property that for all convergent sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements in $A$ we have $\lim_nx_n \in A$, then $A$ is closed in $M$.

As a hint, if for all $\varepsilon>0$ you know that $U_\varepsilon(x) \cap B \neq \varnothing$ then you know that for all $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ there exists $x_n \in U_{1/n}(x) \cap B$. Can you continue from here?